# Bash apt-get updater script via desktop laucher

Tags: linux, shell-script, apt, gnome3, non-root-user

I have a basic apt-get updater script that I am able to launch as root on GNOME3 via the main menu (alacarte). I'd like to be able to launch this script by double clicking via the desktop while signed in as a regular user. What would be the recommended way to do this? I've tried to add "sudo" to the command in the launcher, but that didn't seem to work.

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

Comment: perhaps [this ubuntu answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/118843/421483) is appropriate.

Comment: I've tried many variations and still the script does not work when trying to launch from the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run `apt-get` as a normal user, you will need to add a line to your `/etc/sudoers` file to allow you to execute specific commands with no password.

First, change your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

Second, add the following line to your `/etc/sudoers` file:

`yourusername ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get`

Where `yourusername` is the user name of the user who wants to execute `apt-get` with no password.

Comment: For more information, you can check out the `NOPASSWD` section for the `sudoers` man page here: http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers

Comment: My goal is not to run without a password. I'd just like to be able to launch the script by double clicking the icon from the main menu. I want it to prompt me for a password. When I try and launch it now, nothing happens. The script does launch if executed from the terminal with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further review, I believe the script was launching correctly, but there was a problem encountered during the apt-get, related to the libc6 package. I am using a Debian rolling release OS and just found out about Unattended Upgrades. I'll be looking more into how to properly use this feature.